# Configure MFTF in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, testing, mftf

I have gone thruogh the Magnto doc for MFTF but not getting proper setup.Can any one help me on this.

Comment: which error you are facing?

Comment: I facing slenium driver connectivity issue.